# How to make a part of BufferGeometry Transparent?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a very large mesh for which i have been using `THREE.BufferGeometry`. Users can select some parts of the mesh and make it transparent. For this i have tried to add `alpha` value for each item of `color` attribute and also made my material transparent. But it simply does not work.

I came to know that i have to use `THREE.RawShaderMaterial` and pass a custom attribute of `vec4`. But the problem is i have to use `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` for the lightings. I just dont want to do the lighting calculations by myself in shaders.

Could anyone please tell me is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: this may not be easy to do. What kind of information do you want to use to make a "part" or your geometry transparent, i.e how do you define that part? Is it texture, is it vertex color, is it something else?

Comment: simply copy the program that MeshPhongMaterial has and create a shader from that program, add few lines in it reading a custom attribute (does not have to be vec4, 1 float will suffice) you will need to add code into vertex shader to pass the attribute value to fragment shader through varying and in fragment shader call `discard;` to make the fragment dissapear see it at https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/discard.php the programs of meshphong can be extracted from console or you can copy its creation process from THREEjs code at GIT